# Redux store data is not passing from slice.ts to List.tsx

Tags: typescript, redux

I never worked with Redux, so I have no experience with it and don't know its terminology, so please excuse for any mistakes.
I have 2 pages and the task is to create 1 more page (Clients) almost similar to these two.

```
├── Clients  # it is the page I have to create
│   ├── components
│   │   ├── Item.tsx
│   │   └── List.tsx
│   ├── index.tsx
│   ├── slice.ts
│   └── styles.scss
├── index.tsx
├── ProductsLicenses
│   ├── components
│   │   ├── Item.tsx
│   │   ├── List.tsx
│   │   └── ProductLicenseAddModal.tsx
│   ├── index.tsx
│   ├── slice.ts
│   └── styles.scss
├── store.ts
└── UsersLicenses
    ├── components
    │   ├── ClientAddModal.tsx
    │   ├── ClientComputersListModal.tsx
    │   ├── ClientEditModal.tsx
    │   ├── Item.tsx
    │   └── List.tsx
    ├── index.tsx
    ├── slice.ts
    └── styles.scss
```

The logic is pretty simple, 'slice.ts' has some code to interact with backend server, fetch data and then (as I understand) store it in Redux storage. Then, 'List.tsx' renders a list of items, 'Item.tsx' is describing one single item of collection, and 'index.tsx' is responsible for representing the page.
However, when 'ProductsLicenses' and 'UsersLicenses' works fine, I have the problem with 'Clients'.
It is my `Clients/slice.ts` code:

```
import { createSlice, createAction, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { getClientsList, Client } from "@tms/api";


interface InitialState {
    isFetching: boolean;
    isFetchingError: boolean;
    byId: Record<number, any>;
    ids: Array<number>;
}

const initialState: InitialState = {
    isFetching: true,
    isFetchingError: false,
    byId: {},
    ids: [],
};


const clients = createSlice({
    name: 'clients',
    initialState: initialState,
    reducers: {
        fetchingPending: (state) => ({
            ...state,
            isFetching: true,
        }),
        fetchingSuccess: (state, { payload }) => ({
            ...state,
            isFetching: false,
            byId: payload.byId,
            ids: payload.ids,
        }),
        fetchingError: (state) => ({
            ...state,
            isFetching: false,
            isFetchingError: true,
        }),
    }
});

export const loadClients = () => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(clients.actions.fetchingPending());
    getClientsList().then(json => {
        const ids = json.items.map(item => item.id);
        const byId = json.items.reduce((obj, item) => ({
            ...obj,
            [item.id]: item,
        }), {});
        console.log('ids', ids);  # works fine!
        dispatch(clients.actions.fetchingSuccess({ byId, ids }));
    }).catch(err => {
        dispatch(clients.actions.fetchingError());
    });
}


export default clients;
```

But when we go to the `Clients/components/List.tsx`:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

import { ListLoading } from '@tms/shared/components/ListStates';
import ClientItem, { ClientItemEmpty } from './Item';


const ClientsList = (props) => {
    const isFetching = useSelector((state: any) => state.clients.isFetching);
    const clientIds = useSelector((state: any) => state.clients.ids);
    console.log('isFetching', isFetching');  # undefined;
    console.log('clientIds', clientIds); # empty array;
```

the `state.clients` provides initialized values (unchanged)
plus I notice that in console, 'List.tsx' console.logs() run first, and 'slice.ts' logs() run after them.

For example, `ProductLicenses/slice.ts`has this function:

```
export const loadProductsLicenses = () => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(productsLicenses.actions.fetchingPending());
    licenseGetAllForManager().then(json => {
        const ids = json.items.map(item => item.id);
        const byId = json.items.reduce((obj, item) => ({
            ...obj,
            [item.id]: item,
        }), {});
        console.log('ids', ids);  # works fine; 
        dispatch(productsLicenses.actions.fetchingSuccess({ byId, ids }));
        dispatch(setCurrentProductLicense(ids[0])); // select first product by default
    }).catch(err => {
        dispatch(productsLicenses.actions.fetchingError());
    });
}
```

and `ProductsLicenses/components/List.tsx`:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

import { ListLoading } from '@tms/shared/components/ListStates';
import ProductItem, { ProductItemEmpty } from './Item';


const ProductsList = (props) => {
    const isFetching = useSelector((state: any) => state.productsLicenses.isFetching)
    const productsIds = useSelector((state: any) => state.productsLicenses.ids)
    console.log('isFetching', isFetching);  # works fine
```

here, the 'slice.ts' logs always run first.

IDK what's the issue. I hope that I provide enough of code. Thanks for your comments/answers.

Answer (score 0):

I've waste a couple of hours to solve the issue, then I go here and provide a code for you. However, in a minute after that I've realized that it is a names conflict:
`Clients/slice.ts`:

```
export default clients;
```

`UsersLicense/slice.ts`:

```
export const clients = createClientsSlice('clients');
```

then, I renamed the first const to `clientsList` :)

Be careful with names!